# need and scope of transaction isolation - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, concurrency, transactions

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read

> "All consistent reads within the same transaction read the snapshot
>   established by the first read."

1. What does this snapshot contain? Only a snapshot of the rows read by the first read, of the complete table or even complete database?

Actually I thought only a snapshot of the rows read by the first read, but this confuses me:

TRANSACTION 1 is started at first, then 2. The result of the last "SELECT * FROM B;" in T1 is EXACTLY the same as if I had not executed T2 meanwhile (NEITHER the UPDATE nor the INSERT appear and that, although the read and write are on DIFFERENT tables)

#### TRANSACTION 1:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

START TRANSACTION;

SELECT * FROM A WHERE a_id = 1;
SELECT SLEEP(8);
SELECT * FROM B;

COMMIT;
```

---

#### TRANSACTION 2

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE B SET b_name = 'UPDATE_6' WHERE b_id = 2;
INSERT INTO B (b_name) VALUES('NEW_5');

COMMIT;
```

#### OUTPUTS of TRANSACTION 1

```
# 1st query
a_id  a_name
1     a_1

# 3rd query
b_id b_name
1    b_1
2    b_2
3    b_3
```

---

2. In my web application a PHP script imports data from files in a MySQL database (InnoDB). It is made sure by the application, that there is just this 1 writing process at the same time. However there may be additionally multiple concurrent readers.
   Now I wonder, whether I should and if yes how I can prevent the following:

in one repeatable-read transaction:

- reader R1 reads from table T1
- reader R1 does sth. else
- reader R1 reads from table T2

If data in T1 and T2 belong together in any way, it could happen, that the reader reads in the 1st step some data and in the 3rd step the related data, that now might not be related anymore, because a writer has changed T1 AND T2 meanwhile. AFAIK repeatable-read only guarantees, that the same reads return the same data, but the 2nd read is not the same as the 1st one.

I hope, you know, what I mean, and I fear, that I got sth. totally wrong about this topic.

(a week ago I asked this question in MySQL forum without answers: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,629710,629710#msg-629710)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snapshot is for all the tables in database. The MySQL documentation states that explicitly multiple times here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-consistent-read.html:

> A consistent read means that InnoDB uses multi-versioning to present
>   to a query a snapshot of the **database** at a point in time.

and

> Suppose that you are running in the default REPEATABLE READ isolation
>   level. When you issue a consistent read (that is, an ordinary SELECT
>   statement), InnoDB gives your transaction a timepoint according to
>   which your query sees the **database**.

and

> The snapshot of the **database** state applies to SELECT statements within
>   a transaction, not necessarily to DML statements.

Comment: OK. So repeatable read in MySQL does actually much more than "it has to". I could find further information here: https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/repeatable_read_isolation_level_in×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 If you read on Wikipedia be careful not to overlook "a _lock-based_ concurrency control DBMS implementation", as I did. minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: What is about my question 2? My conclusion is, that the described problem can not appear. However, I had to put all reads in the same transaction, so that MySQL would have to keep the snapshots for a pretty long time. Is that a problem, if writes occur not that often? Actually it does not have to create a snapshot, if there is no one writing. I think I should use  START TRANSACTION READ ONLY. (see http://bit.ly/19M9R5a) However I wonder, how it is usually done in applications, do you really put all the reads in the same transactions or do you accept the "risk"?

Comment: Putting all the reads into same transaction is the right thing to do if application cares about consistency between the reads. You did not quantify "pretty long time", but I wouldn't worry about it too much. Snapshots are not expensive, because the way they are typically implemented - there is no actual copying of the data, instead database keeps track of timestamps and know which inserts and which deletes should be visible to which transactions.